# Insert data to table Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I use the following code to inser data in table:

```
$order = new OrderProduct();
        $order->save([
            "created_at" => Carbon::now(),
            "user_id" => $user->id,
            "note" => $request->note
        ]);
```

Model `OrderProduct` is:

```
class OrderProduct extends Model
{

    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $table = "class OrderProduct extends Model
```

{

```
public $timestamps = true;

protected $table = "order_product";

protected $fillable = [
    'order_id', 'status', 'user_id', 'note'
];";

    protected $fillable = [
        'order_id', 'status', 'user_id', 'note'
    ];
}
```

Why I always get `user_id` is equal 0 in table `order_product`?

I tried also replace `$user->id` to real value :

```
$order->save([
                "created_at" => Carbon::now(),
                "user_id" => 2,
                "note" => $request->note
            ]);
```

But again get zero value in this field.

Type of `user_id` is:

```
| user_id    | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL
```

Comment: What happens if you use insert a record with pure SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding it this way:

```
$order = new OrderProduct();
$order->user_id = 2;
$order->note = $noteHere;
$order->save():
```

By default Laravel adds the timestamp to the created_at and updated_at columns.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Perfect! Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

controller.php

```
      $name  = $request->name;
     $email  = $request->email;
        $data = array(
            "name" =>  $name,
            "email"=>  $email
            );

        $q = DB::table('users')->insert($data);
```